# Load page into source

Tags: jquery

I have this static code, works fine for generating an pulldownmenu for inline editing.

```
<script>
$('.editable_selectfield_1').editable({
    source: [
      {value: '1', text: 'Overig'},
      {value: '2', text: 'Constructiestaal'},
      {value: '3', text: 'Constructiestaal (fijn)'},
      {value: '4', text: 'Ketelplaat'},
      {value: '5', text: 'Ketelplaat (ASME)'},
      {value: '6', text: 'Ketelplaat (fijn)'},
      {value: '7', text: 'Scheepsbouw'},
      {value: '8', text: 'Hoge sterkte'},
      {value: '9', text: 'Slijtvast'},
      {value: '10', text: 'RVS'},
      {value: '11', text: 'Offshore'},
   ],
});
</script>
```

But I need this dynamcly, so I have moved the contents to an new file `includes/test.php`
For testing I have placed the content there as static like

```
<?php
echo "
  {value: '1', text: 'Overig'},
  {value: '2', text: 'Constructiestaal'},
  {value: '3', text: 'Constructiestaal (fijn)'},
  {value: '4', text: 'Ketelplaat'},
  {value: '5', text: 'Ketelplaat (ASME)'},
  {value: '6', text: 'Ketelplaat (fijn)'},
  {value: '7', text: 'Scheepsbouw'},
  {value: '8', text: 'Hoge sterkte'},
  {value: '9', text: 'Slijtvast'},
  {value: '10', text: 'RVS'},
  {value: '11', text: 'Offshore'},
";
?>
```

Now I have changed the script to

```
    <script>
$('.editable_selectfield_1').editable({
    source: [('includes/test.php').load]
});

    </script>
```

I am getting no errors in the console. But the list is returned empty. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: use `source: [<?php include_once 'includes/test.php'?>]`

Comment: Nice @RoyBogado :)

Comment: Glad to help, good coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the [PHP include](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.include.php)
`source: [<?php include_once 'includes/test.php'?>]`